# How to resize browser window for screenshots on Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, screenshot, testcafe, window-resize

When running a test in Testcafe, I'd like to resize the browser for screenshots.
As described in https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/resize-window.html#setting-the-window-size, I've tried the following:

(1) `"testcafe \"chrome:headless --window-size='width,height'\"`

(2) `await t.resizeWindow(width,height)`

For some reason, the screenshots dimensions that are returned are twice the size: 2400x1690. Has anyone else encountered this and know how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are using a HighDPI display and scale 200%?

Comment: For me, this only happens with Chrome :s